Issues on compiling a journal template
I am having issues with the following LaTeX template.
One of my papers has been accepted in the following journal https://sciendo.com/journal/IJMCE. The journal wants me to write the paper in their template but I am not able to compile my manuscript in the given template.
I had copied the code of the LaTeX template provided by the journal but I am unable to compile the file.

Can someone please help me out? If someone can please guide me, I shall be extremely grateful.
\documentclass{amans}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amans}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}


%*****************************************************************
%  
%*****************************************************************
\Volume[2023]{1}{1}

%*****************************************************************
%   
%*****************************************************************
\newcount\primera
\primera=1
\Page{\primera} 

\doinumber{10.2478/ijmce-2023-0000}     
%*****************************************************************
 
%*****************************************************************
%   
%*****************************************************************
\def\proof{{\noindent \it Proof. }}
\theoremstyle{definition}  
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\theoremstyle{remark}   
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}
\theoremstyle{plain}   
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
%:
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{coro}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{conj}[theorem]{Conjecture}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\newtheorem {note} [theorem] {Note}
\newtheorem {problem} [theorem] {Open Problem}


%*****************************************************************
% 
\authormark{The last name of Corresponding Author, }
%*****************************************************************


%*****************************************************************
%  
%*****************************************************************
\titlemark{ The short title of article}
 


\begin{document}
\label{firstpage}
\title{\first{{\footnotesize \textbf{Original Study}}\\
Title of this article should be written in here properly }}

%Author names should be written in clear and detail.
\setcounter{footnote}{1}
%**********************************************************************************************************
\author{}

\address{}
%**********************************************************************************************************
\abstract{
\begin{table}[h!]
\vspace*{-1mm}
 \doublerulesep 0.05pt \tabcolsep 7.8mm 
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{7.5pt}
\hspace*{-1.5mm}
\begin{tabular*}{171.45mm}{r|||||l}
\multicolumn{2}{r}{\rule[-6pt]{170.45mm}{.09pt}}\\[2mm]
\multicolumn{2}{l}{
\parbox[t]{15cm}{\small
\vspace*{.5mm}
\footnotesize \center{Communicated by Haci Mehmet Baskonus; Received: 00.00.2023; Accepted: 00.00.2023; Online: 00.00.2023}
}}
\\
\multicolumn{2}{r}{\rule[-6pt]{170.45mm}{.1pt}}\\[2mm]
\noalign{\vspace{2mm}}
%**********************************************************************************************************%***************************
%  Abstract 
%**********************************************************************************************************%***********************************
\multicolumn{2}{c}{
\parbox[t]{\hsize}{
\vspace*{.5mm}
{\normalsize\bf Abstract}\par
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{.8}
\normalsize \vspace*{1mm} {\small The abstract should be written properly and informative way. The abstract should be written properly and informative way. 
}
\par
\par
\par
\hfill{\scriptsize
}
}
}
\\
\multicolumn{2}{r}{\parbox[t]{17cm}{\vbox{\hsize 17cm{\footnotesize\bf Keywords:} \footnotesize Baskonus, Mehmet, Keywords.
\par 
%Write here the AMS 2020 codes which it may be found via "https://mathscinet.ams.org/msnhtml/msc2020.pdf "
{\footnotesize\bf AMS 2020 codes:} \footnotesize 35C07; 35Dxx; 45Kxx; 65Mxx; 45K05.}
}}\\[-4mm]
\multicolumn{2}{r}{\rule[-6pt]{170.45mm}{.9pt}}\\
%**********************************************************************************************************%************************************
\end{tabular*}
\vspace*{-5mm}
\end{table}
}

\maketitle
\thispagestyle{fancy}


\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}
\normalsize
\vspace*{5mm}

\section{Introduction}\label{section1}






\begin{thebibliography}{999}

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}

Error Message I am receiving: dfTeX error: pdflatex (file gbksong25): Font gbksong25 at 540 not found

Please note, questions here should be self-containing. External links to example code can always become invalid and then the while question would be useless. So please reduce your code to a minimal working example and add it to your question. Also copy&paste the original error message(s) from the log file. From the screenshot I would guess that font files are missing.

BTW: Loading lmodern before package amans does not make much sense, because amans loads font packages for rm, sf, and tt and therefore overwrites lmodern.

somewhere in code you have not shown you are specifying the gbksong font which overleaf apparently does not have,  so you need to use a different font or (more complicated) upload that font to your overleaf project)

Addendum to my initial comment: Adding an Overleaf link as well/instead of MWE explains why such links should be avoided.

@DavidCarlisle; Can you please help me how to solve the problem, I am clueless

@cabohah; I understand pasting links here is not expected, but I don't know how to post my problem here without posting the link

No sorry you have given no information that would allow anyone to guess an answer. somewhere in code you have not shown you are acessing the Chinese font gbksong in a way that is causing an error. If you don't have Chinese in your document you simply need to not reference the font, if you do you need to reference a Chinese font, you need to use one that overleaf has but without seeing any code or any of your document it is impossible to say

@Olivia See the link in my first comment. Currently we cannot tell you much more than David and me already have.

@DavidCarlisle; I have added the code, Please check if you can help me now

@cabohah; I have provided the code, Can you please help me now? I am stuck at why its not working

can you give a link to amans,cls to save mne reading the entire publisher website looking for it?

You should ask for advice, because even the template file doesn't compile.
The problem is that the class, for some unknown reason, tries to typeset the whole document inside a CJK* environment:
\def\amans@beginCJK{
  \begin{CJK*}{GBK}{rm}\CJKtilde
}
\def\amans@endCJK{
  \label{lastpage}
  \clearpage
  \end{CJK*}
}
\let\amans@begindocumenthook\@begindocumenthook
\let\amans@enddocumenthook\@enddocumenthook
\def\AtBeginDocument{\g@addto@macro\amans@begindocumenthook}
\def\AtEndDocument{\g@addto@macro\amans@enddocumenthook}
\def\@begindocumenthook{\amans@begindocumenthook\amans@beginCJK}
\def\@enddocumenthook{\amans@endCJK\amans@enddocumenthook}

In order to do this it changes kernel commands. This has always been dangerous and not recommended.
Since recent LaTeX kernels have changed the “begin document” and “end document” hook management, LaTeX gets thoroughly confused.
Hack: remove CJK, but inform the copy editors about it.
%%% NOTES for the copy editors
%%% 1. the first line marked '% <--- NO CJK' avoids loading CJK
%%% 2. the second line marked '% <--- NO CJK' avoids LaTeX errors
%%% 3. the class should be amended, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/730049/

%%%
\expandafter\def\csname ver@CJK.sty\endcsname{3000/12/31} % <--- NO CJK
%%%

\documentclass{amans}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amans}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

%%%
\newenvironment{CJK*}[2]{}{}\newcommand{\CJKtilde}{} % <--- NO CJK
%%%

%*****************************************************************
%  
%*****************************************************************
\Volume[2023]{1}{1}

%*****************************************************************
%   
%*****************************************************************
\newcount\primera
\primera=1
\Page{\primera} 

\doinumber{10.2478/ijmce-2023-0000}     
%*****************************************************************
 
%*****************************************************************
%   
%*****************************************************************
\def\proof{{\noindent \it Proof. }}
\theoremstyle{definition}  
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\theoremstyle{remark}   
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}
\theoremstyle{plain}   
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
%:
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{coro}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{conj}[theorem]{Conjecture}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\newtheorem {note} [theorem] {Note}
\newtheorem {problem} [theorem] {Open Problem}


%*****************************************************************
% 
\authormark{The last name of Corresponding Author, }
%*****************************************************************


%*****************************************************************
%  
%*****************************************************************
\titlemark{ The short title of article}
 


\begin{document}
\label{firstpage}
\title{\first{{\footnotesize \textbf{Original Study}}\\
Title of this article should be written in here properly }}

%Author names should be written in clear and detail.
\setcounter{footnote}{1}
%**********************************************************************************************************
\author{}

\address{}
%**********************************************************************************************************
\abstract{
\begin{table}[h!]
\vspace*{-1mm}
 \doublerulesep 0.05pt \tabcolsep 7.8mm 
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{7.5pt}
\hspace*{-1.5mm}
\begin{tabular*}{171.45mm}{r|||||l}
\multicolumn{2}{r}{\rule[-6pt]{170.45mm}{.09pt}}\\[2mm]
\multicolumn{2}{l}{
\parbox[t]{15cm}{\small
\vspace*{.5mm}
\footnotesize \center{Communicated by Haci Mehmet Baskonus; Received: 00.00.2023; Accepted: 00.00.2023; Online: 00.00.2023}
}}
\\
\multicolumn{2}{r}{\rule[-6pt]{170.45mm}{.1pt}}\\[2mm]
\noalign{\vspace{2mm}}
%**********************************************************************************************************%***************************
%  Abstract 
%**********************************************************************************************************%***********************************
\multicolumn{2}{c}{
\parbox[t]{\hsize}{
\vspace*{.5mm}
{\normalsize\bf Abstract}\par
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{.8}
\normalsize \vspace*{1mm} {\small The abstract should be written properly and informative way. The abstract should be written properly and informative way. 
}
\par
\par
\par
\hfill{\scriptsize
}
}
}
\\
\multicolumn{2}{r}{\parbox[t]{17cm}{\vbox{\hsize 17cm{\footnotesize\bf Keywords:} \footnotesize Baskonus, Mehmet, Keywords.
\par 
%Write here the AMS 2020 codes which it may be found via "https://mathscinet.ams.org/msnhtml/msc2020.pdf "
{\footnotesize\bf AMS 2020 codes:} \footnotesize 35C07; 35Dxx; 45Kxx; 65Mxx; 45K05.}
}}\\[-4mm]
\multicolumn{2}{r}{\rule[-6pt]{170.45mm}{.9pt}}\\
%**********************************************************************************************************%************************************
\end{tabular*}
\vspace*{-5mm}
\end{table}
}

\maketitle
\thispagestyle{fancy}


\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}
\normalsize
\vspace*{5mm}

\section{Introduction}\label{section1}






\begin{thebibliography}{999}

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}



Dear egreg, it is working.  I don't know how to thank you for this. You are truly awesome. You are one of the most beautiful person here in TeX stack exchange. I thank you from the core of my heart. I wish I could meet you in person and thank you for this. Love you dear !!
